# Smart-table date and amount sorting which is in string format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-sorting, smart-table

In smart-table, sorting is easy. But when the date and amount are in string format, how to sort?

```
app.controller('basicsCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {scope.rowCollection = [
{firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate:'1987-05-21', balance: '1,20,000', email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
{firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: '1987-04-25', balance: '2,000', email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
{firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: '1955-08-27', balance: '4,23,000', email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}];
}]);
```

I am not able to use, the format function inside my json. Its throwing error.

```
formatFunction: function (value, formatParameter) {
return value[0];// some function to change string to date.
}
```

Following this doc. http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

Is there anyone to help me? I am new to this area...

Comment: For parsing dates, I recommend http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter to format dates from a string

```
app.filter('formatter', function () {
    return function (inputArray) {
        angular.forEach(inputArray,function(item,index){
            item.birthDate = new Date(item.birthDate)
        });
        return inputArray;
    };
});
```

Then use it in html:

```
<smart-table rows="rowCollection | formatter"></smart-table>
```